# Spring Integration http:outbound-gateway using json subparts

Tags: json, spring, http, spring-integration

I hope the title is clear. I am using Spring Integration and I would like to do followings. I would like to consume the following api to enrich a payload: https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemultifull?fsyms=BTC&tsyms=USD

As you see it has a structure like RAW/BTC/USD/ and then attributes. I am only interested in a few attribute values.

My outbound-gateway is as following and works so far:

```
<int:chain input-channel="internal.cryptocompare.coin.market.enrich.channel">
    <int-http:outbound-gateway id="cryptocompareHttpGateway.marketData" 
        url="https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemultifull?fsyms={fsym}&amp;tsyms={tsyms}"
        http-method="GET" 
        reply-timeout="10000" 
        charset="UTF-8"
    >
        <int-http:uri-variable name="fsym" expression="payload.symbol" />
        <int-http:uri-variable name="tsyms" expression="'USD'" />
    </int-http:outbound-gateway>
</int:chain>
```

I get then a `ResponseEntity` which I would like to get the attributes e.g. PRICE.

Instead having a `ResponseEntity` I would also have a value object what I could use too, but the fields were not enriched:

```
<int:enricher id="coinMarketEnricher"
    input-channel="internal.cryptocompare.coin.price.enriched.income.channel"
    request-channel="internal.cryptocompare.coin.market.enrich.channel"
    output-channel="cryptocompare.income.channel"
    error-channel="cryptocompare.error.channel"
>
    <int:property name="volume24hUSD" expression="payload.volume24hUSD"/>
    <int:property name="marketCapUSD" expression="payload.marketCapUSD"/>
    <int:property name="availableSupply" expression="payload.availableSupply"/>
    <int:property name="changePercent24h" expression="payload.changePercent24h"/>
    <int:property name="lastUpdateEpoch" expression="payload.lastUpdateEpoch"/>
    <int:property name="marketName" expression="payload.marketName"/>
</int:enricher>

<int:channel id="internal.cryptocompare.coin.market.enrich.channel" />

<int:chain input-channel="internal.cryptocompare.coin.market.enrich.channel">
    <int-http:outbound-gateway id="cryptocompareHttpGateway.marketData" 
        url="https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemultifull?fsyms={fsym}&amp;tsyms={tsyms}"
        http-method="GET" 
        reply-timeout="10000" 
        charset="UTF-8"
        expected-response-type="net.hemisoft.ccm.porter.cryptocompare.Coin"
    >
        <int-http:uri-variable name="fsym" expression="payload.symbol" />
        <int-http:uri-variable name="tsyms" expression="'USD'" />
    </int-http:outbound-gateway>
</int:chain>

@ToString
class Coin {
    @JsonProperty("Id")                 String  coinId
    @JsonProperty("CoinName")           String  name
    @JsonProperty("Name")               String  symbol
    @JsonProperty("SortOrder")          Integer rank
    @JsonProperty("USD")                Double  priceUSD
    @JsonProperty("BTC")                Double  priceBTC
    @JsonProperty("VOLUME24HOUR")       Double  volume24hUSD
    @JsonProperty("MKTCAP")             Double  marketCapUSD
    @JsonProperty("SUPPLY")             Double  availableSupply
    @JsonProperty("CHANGEPCT24HOUR")    Double  changePercent24h
    @JsonProperty("LASTUPDATE")         Long    lastUpdateEpoch
    @JsonProperty("LASTMARKET")         String  marketName
}
```

I would prefer using Coin_Class over Response-Entity.
Thank you very much for your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that purpose you need to add this:

```
expected-response-type="Coin"
```

into the `<int-http:outbound-gateway>` definition: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.4.RELEASE/reference/html/http.html#_httprequestexecutingmessagehandler

> Further to the note above regarding empty response bodies, if a response does contain a body, you must provide an appropriate `expected-response-type` attribute or, again, you will simply receive a `ResponseEntity` with no body.

**UPDATE**

Since a JSON you get doesn't fit your `Coin` model directly you can do it like:

- Send `new Coin` to the `internal.cryptocompare.coin.price.enriched.income.channel`
- The `request-channel="internal.cryptocompare.coin.market.enrich.channel"` will perform an HTTP request
- There instead of `expected-response-type="net.hemisoft.ccm.porter.cryptocompare.Coin"`, you should use `expected-response-type="java.lang.String"`
- Then in those `<int:property>` for mapping you need to perform `#jsonPath()` to extract required values, e.g.  `<int:property name="volume24hUSD" expression="#jsonPath(payload, '$..VOLUME24HOUR[1]')"/>`

See more info here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.4.RELEASE/reference/html/spel.html and here: https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath

Comment: Hi Artem, thank you for your answer. The expected-response-type I am using already. The Problem is, that the attributes I want to populate are still empty. The Json what comes back is nested (see: https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemultifull?fsyms=BTC&tsyms=USD). But I need the attributes of the "leafes". See the second part of code snippets.

Comment: Please, find an UPDATE in my answer.

Comment: Hey Artem, thats exactly what I am looking for. Thank you very much :-)

Comment: Small question, when I do `$..VOLUME24HOUR` then I get the array, what is correct as `[1.046322759001319E8, DOGE 104,632,275.9]`, when I do `$..VOLUME24HOUR[0]` or `$..VOLUME24HOUR[1]`, I get an empty array instead of the first element.

Comment: What works for now is `#jsonPath(payload, '$..VOLUME24HOUR')[0]`, but not sure it is an elegant way.

Comment: Yeah... I see the same behavior. I think it isn't going to work with the final leaves. You may just specify a direct path to the first leaf: `$.RAW.BTC.USD.VOLUME24HOUR`. This is much efficient, than array and indexing afterwards.